# Wrong frame rate when saving camera feed to a file using FFMPEG

Tags: camera, ffmpeg, stream

I'm trying to save the live feed from an IP camera to a file but the resulting file always plays much faster than the original speed.

I have tried with the following commands:

```
ffmpeg -i http://171.22.3.47/image -vcodec copy -an -t 900 c:\output.mp4

ffmpeg -i http://171.22.3.47/image -c:v libx264 -an c:\output.mp4
```

Does anybody know what I'm missing? Both commands create the file and I can use Windows Media Player to play them, but they run much faster.

Comment: To the person who downvoted me, could you give me a reason why my question is not appropiate?

Comment: My guess for the downvotes is that: 1) SO is for programming questions only so yours is offtopic (see [su]). 2) You provided no console outputs from your commands.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's weird because before posting my question I researched a lot about ffmpeg and what parameters to use to save a stream to a file, and most of what I found was on stackoverflow. See this one for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259588/how-to-dump-raw-rtsp-stream-to-file

Comment: That's also offtopic. It's a common occurrence.

Comment: full command line and uncut console output please?

Comment: Did you try to set framerate manually with `-r 25` option?

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing output framerate by adding `-r` key

```
ffmpeg -i http://171.22.3.47/image -c:v libx264 -an -r 30 c:\output.mp4
```

You can also try to slow down the resulting video as an option. This will make `output.mp4` 2 times slower:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=2.0*PTS" -c:v libx264 -an output-slow.mp4
```

Comment: I can't force the frame rate because on a live feed it's variable, it's not fixed. Slowing down it won't work either. I lost my reputation points for nothing with your answer...

Comment: Why slowing video down won't work? The command from my reply doesn't work you it's not an option for you? If the former is correct, please, add this information to your question (console output for my command).