# How to store a raw RTSP video stream to a file?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, save, rtsp, live-streaming

I'm playing around with the open source FFMpeg tool. I want to save an RTSP video stream to a local file. I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259588/how-to-dump-raw-rtsp-stream-to-file) and I tried executing a similar command, but its not working. It doesn't throw any error either. My command is:
`ffmpeg -i rtsp://test.vibrtech.com/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C2100F124^&channel=2^&GUID=betauser -acodec copy -vcodec copy c:/video.mp4`
but when I execute this command all I'm getting is this(with the cursor being blinked like forever, until I manually invoke `ctrl+c`):

```
D:\..\bin>ffmpeg -i rtsp://test.vibrtech.com/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C2100F124^&channel=2^&GUID=betauser -acodec copy -vcodec copy c:/video.mp4

ffmpeg version N-77704-g68eb208 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls 
--enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca 
--enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm 
--enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame 
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg 
--enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger 
--enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame 
--enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp 
--enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid 
--enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 12.100 / 55. 12.100
  libavcodec     57. 21.100 / 57. 21.100
  libavformat    57. 21.100 / 57. 21.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
_
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Or is there any way this could be achieved by using other commands?
**P.S**: I'm getting the stream from this url: rtsp://test.vibrtech.com/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C2100F124&channel=2&GUID=betaUser

Comment: You have `^` symbol inside *url* in your first command, but there's no `^`  in the command posted after **P.S.**. Is it normal?

Comment: Also, when I tried your command `ffmpeg` failed to resolve hostname.

Comment: @Edgar Rokyan You can't access it because this stream is only accessible internally for testing purpose  and I've used `^` in the command because cmd doesn't accept `&` so we have to use this caret symbol or have to use quotes for the entire url.